# PHP Website creating files performance bottle neck

Tags: php, apache

I have a LAMP website built with PHP.  I have a page like `http://myproject.com/report-download.php` with a button that says `Export CSV`.  When a user clicks on the button, they get a csv file with some report data that was originally in a MySQL database.  This works great when I have only a few records.  But when I have 1 million records, it takes a lot longer for the page to grab the data and create the csv file.  During this CSV creation period, it takes a really long time for the user to go from one page to another on the website.

How do PHP developers normally get around the slow page load issue while the web server is still working on the CSV generation?  Do I get around this with PHP threading?  Or is there something I'm supposed to do to apache?

**Addition**

```
I create the csv file kinda like this

while($row = $db->getData($pageNumber))
{
   add_to_file('file.csv.inprogress',array_to_csv($row));
   $pageNumber++;
}

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo file_get_contents('file.csv.inprogress');
```

But it takes a long time to create the csv file, so during this time, the page load time is really slow fo rthe user.

Comment: We cache. You may want to invest in memcached or redis instances and cache data there. Additionally, save the report so when the next request is identical, you just serve the already-generated files.

Comment: php has no native threading. "really long" ? If you using sessions, then the session is locked by whichever script is actively running. try `session_write_close()` before you go into any long-running code sections, so the lock gets released and other pages can be viewed.

Comment: The only time I had an issue with a server acting slow during file writing, I upgraded to a solid state drive. Problem is now gone :p There are many ways to solve this, but adding a cache on pages which can be cached will help. I wouldn't necessarily consider this a programming problem though but more a server administration/hardware/configuration problem - my two cents.

Comment: If the reports take a really long time to generate and are not suitable for caching, you can always generate it using a backend shell process and have the client come back for it later when it's finished. If the load on the database from the generation is too high, you could consider maintaining a read-only db mirror for report generation.

Comment: if you are just talking about the page load time for the user that the csv is generated for, then it might help to do it with an asynchronous call using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd push the file creation to the background by running

```
exec('nohup php script_that_creates_csv.php');
```

add a DB entry when the script is finished and check the DB every n seconds for this entry using AJAX. This way you/your user will most likely not be bothered with the execution and creation of your csv.

The called script should contain code to create your csv and to insert the actual state to your DB

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of PHP you are using, you can use caching extensions such as APC, Xcache, OPCache, Eaccelerator or Memcached. They all have similar benchmarks and up/downs.

Here is a quick guide on ups and down. 
 * Xcache is easy to install and works great, especially with a light speed server.
 * APC is no longer supported by PHP 5.5 and is replaced with OPCache
 * Memcached is good when you have multiple servers or a load balancer.

You can also use file caching but its resource intensive and not the fastest.

Apache shouldn't have to much to to with it in most situations, but you can try NGINX and see what improvement you have. In some situations it improves speed 10 fold, its hard to say without knowing what exactly your URL is and purpose of your site.

Comment: the caching you talk about is for better memory management right?   If I **expect** report generation to take a long time simply because there's a lot of data to export, I'm still going to run into slow page load issue throughout the site for that user until that report generation is complete. Right?

Comment: [read this SO link for explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082092/different-file-caching-methods-pros-cons)

It was closed but read to the answers toward the bottom, Also read this article on serving csv's with PHP

Comment: Also read this article on serving csv's with PHP.

[Create and Stream a CSV with PHP](http://ran.ge/2009/10/27/howto-create-stream-csv-php/)

This may solve your issue.

Comment: What type of server are you using, upgrading servers will also help with this issue.